# Lateral Driven Oscillation of a bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, resonance

I am working through a question on driven oscillations and was looking for a couple of pointers if possible. The question is regarding driven oscillations on a bridge, and we have established the standard damped equation of motion

$$ \ddot{x} + \frac{\alpha}{m}\dot{x} + \frac{k}{m}x = 0$$

I have found that the critical damping coefficient $\alpha$ is $\alpha_{crit} = \sqrt{4km}$, and we are told that the alpha value for the bridge is 1% of this critical damping coefficient.

The questions states that pedestrians make synchronous sideways steps in the direction of the motion, where the force exerted by each person is $F=Pv$ where $v$ is the lateral velocity of the bridge. Amplification begins around 200 people that are approximately 70kg and beyond this motion is effectively negatively damped, and amplitude continues to increase over time.

I need to first find an expression for $P$ in terms of $\alpha_{crit}$ and then find the time taken for amplitudes to reach 70mm, with 300 people walking in step at an initial lateral motion with an amplitude of 1mm.

I am a bit stuck on this part, however. I guess that the driving force will be sinusoidal with the same frequency as the natural frequency of the bridge, given that it is proportional to $v$ (is this right?) but I am not sure then how $P$ relates to the critical damping coefficient.

Sorry for the long question, have been trying to wrap my head around it for a bit and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look back at your notes for deriving eqn. 1. When does $\alpha$ enter? Why? This is the same as the formulation for $P$.

Comment: Sorry, still a bit confused not quite sure what you mean.